# Structure of Hermitian matrices that commutes with all permutation of subsystems?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations

Denote the set $\mathcal S$ all Hermitian matrices act on $\mathbb{C}^d\otimes \mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d$. If for any $H\in\mathcal S$, we have $H$ is invariant under the permutation of subsystems, how can I characterize $\mathcal S$? For example, all linear combinations of tensor product of Hermitian matrices will be permutation invariant, i.e., $H=\sum_i{a_iH_i\otimes H_i\otimes H_i}$.

Comment: There are other permutation invariant matrices as well, for example anything of the form $H \otimes I \otimes I + I \otimes H \otimes I + I \otimes I \otimes H$.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know there are other types. So my question is, what's the structure of those matrices?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a general theorem about the structures of these matrices themselves. Is there a specific property you have in mind?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat related, the algebra formed by all permutation invariant matrices can be described. It is the symmetric tensor product of $3$ copies of $M_d(\mathbb{C})$, so of dimension $\begin{pmatrix} d^2+2\\3 \end{pmatrix}$. It is also isomorphic to a direct sum of three matrix algebras $M_{d_1}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_{d_2}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_{d_3}(\mathbb{C})$, where $d_1 = \begin{pmatrix} d+2\\3 \end{pmatrix}$, $d_2 = \begin{pmatrix} d\\3 \end{pmatrix}$, and $d_3 = \frac{1}{2} (d^3 - \begin{pmatrix} d+2\\3 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} d\\3 \end{pmatrix})$.

Comment: (The three matrix algebra summands correspond to the three different irreducible representations of $S_3$.)

Comment: @DavidGao Em. It seems your first example is a special case of mine. Let's consider a more simple case: $\frac{1}{2}\left( I+H \right) \otimes \left( I+H \right) -\frac{1}{2}\left( I-H \right) \otimes \left( I-H \right) =I\otimes H+H\otimes I$.

Comment: You’re right. I didn’t notice that. Looking at it now, I actually don’t know how to compute the dimension of the space of matrices of the form you wrote down. Perhaps it is even true all Hermitian permutation-invariant matrices are of the form you wrote down? I’ll think about this more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll prove, contrary to my previous thoughts, that in fact all Hermitian permutation invariant matrices are of the form $H = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i H_i \otimes H_i \otimes H_i$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $H_i$ are $d \times d$ Hermitian matrices. I’ll actually prove this more generally for the tensor product of arbitrarily finitely many subsystems, instead of just $3$, i.e., I’ll prove any Hermitian permutation invariant matrix acting on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ is a real linear combination of matrices of the form $H^{\otimes n}$, where $H$ is a $d \times d$ Hermitian matrix.

To start with, recall that the symmetrization map $\mathrm{Sym}$ given by $\mathrm{Sym}(A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} A_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes A_{\sigma(n)}$ is a linear projection from the space of all matrices on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ to the space of all permutation invariant matrices on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$. Observe that $\mathrm{Sym}$ commutes with taking adjoints. Thus, any Hermitian permutation matrix $S$ can be written as $\mathrm{Sym}(T + T^\ast)$ for some matrix $T$ on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$. Any such $T$ can be written as a real linear combination (indeed, even a sum) of simple tensors $A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n$, so $S$ is a real linear combination of matrices of the form,

$$\mathrm{Sym}(A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n + A_1^\ast \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n^\ast)$$

By writing $A_i = \mathrm{Re}(A_i) + i\mathrm{Im}(A_i)$, where $\mathrm{Re}(A_i)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(A_i)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $A_i$, respectively, and are both Hermitian, we see that $\mathrm{Sym}(A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n + A_1^\ast \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n^\ast)$ can be written as a real linear combination of symmetrizations of simple tensors of Hermitian matrices (indeed, of $\mathrm{Re}(A_i)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(A_i)$). Thus, it suffices to show that $\mathrm{Sym}(H_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes H_n)$, where $H_i$ are Hermitian matrices on $\mathbb{C}^d$, are of the desired form.

This simply follows from the following formula,

$$\mathrm{Sym}(H_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes H_n) = \frac{1}{2^nn!} \sum_{(i_1, \cdots, i_n) \in \{ \pm1\}^n} [(\prod_{j=1}^n i_j)(i_1H_1 + \cdots + i_nH_n)^{\otimes n}]$$

You can check this by hand when $n = 3$. I’ll let you run through the combinatorial argument to check this works for general $n$.